# Symfony2 loading time and performance

Tags: performance, symfony, loading

I am working on a not so big project (3 bundles I created and 6 I downloaded / 5 Entities) and I have placed this code on my home controller :

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $time = microtime(true) - $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"];
        echo $time; 
        die();

        //...
```

It's giving me under **100ms** on the localhost (with APC enabled) which is fine.

The real problem is the behavior on the online server (using prod env and APC not installed) : 
If I don't use the website for like 10 minutes, the first time it is really slow to load (**2 to 4 seconds**) and then if I stay on the website, if I refresh the page, it is way faster (**from 500ms to 1s**).

**Is that normal ? Is there something wrong with my online server or my symfony2 project ?**

Comment: Probably a long shot, but do you happen to have xdebug enabled? It has a huge impact on performance.

Comment: I don't. But before trying anything like that, I would like to know if these values are normal or not ?

Comment: They certainly are not normal, if you're running on decent hardware and the environment is prod.

Comment: Thanks you ! I am actually running on good hardware and prod env. What are acceptable values for these case ?

Comment: I tried running the project on my MAC with MAMP and APC enabled (I also tried xCache)... and I get ~30ms instead of ~300ms ! This is surprisingly faster, thanks ! But... since I can't have APC enabled on my online server, I'm still looking for ways to improve that.

Comment: Yeah, APC helps a lot! I guess the next step would be to run the application in dev env and see whether there's a particular area that's slow (really easy with >=2.1.*). Otherwise I'm afraid you'd have to dive into system-wide profiling. I don't unfortunately have enough time to flesh out a proper answer, but [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qsPEHEpddzI) is a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definetly setup APC to decrease the loading time. Here's a note on that:

[Performance](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/book/performance.html)

(2015 edit: link updated)

Comment: Since there is a quite big difference between the local and online version, don't you think it is coming from my symfony2 configuration, my database connexion... and not the execution of PHP ?

Comment: Depends on what PHP version you use on local/remote env, and OS also.

Comment: I tried running the project on my MAC with MAMP and APC enabled (I also tried xCache)... and I get ~30ms instead of ~300ms ! This is surprisingly faster, thanks ! But... since I can't have APC enabled on my online server, I'm still looking for ways to improve that.

Answer (score 2):

Just have a look at the timeline tab of the great toolbar / profiler which Symfony provides:
http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-2-new-stopwatch-component
(not limited to 2.2)

Are you using localhost as the database_host? If so, try 127.0.0.1 instead!

Are you accessing a third party API like Facebook (FOSUserBundle)?

Comment: I am using Symfony v2.0.9 so I am able to install the component ?
I am using 127.0.0.1 and FOSUserBundle.

Comment: The toolbar is definitely available for 2.0.9: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/v2.0.9/app/config/config_dev.yml#L9

How about you update your Symfony version? Made any progress on the rendering time?

Comment: I installed the Stopwatch component using composer but there's nothing new in my web profiler... 
If I ever make it work, will it be able to provide information before the execution of first controller ? (cf my code question)

Comment: You don't need to install anything..just enable the toolbar in the config_dev.yml as shown in the link: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/v2.0.9/app/config/config_dev.yml#L9